# Collection of lambda functions in Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream function `KStream<K, V>[] branch(final Predicate<? super K, ? super V>... predicates)`. I wanted to create a list of predicates dynamically. Is that possible?

```
       KStream<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>[] branches = stream
           .map((key, event) -> enrich(key, event))
           .branch(getStrategies());

        [...]

        private List<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>> getStrategies() {
            ArrayList<Predicate<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            for (MigrationStrategy strategy : strategies) {
                predicates.add(new org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(Long key, AccountMigrationEvent value) {
                        return strategy.match(value);
                    }
                });

            }
            return predicates;
        }
```

Comment: Your method requires an array (`...`), not a list. Why are you using `Predicate` in some places and `org.apache...Predicate` in others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but in theory it should work:

```
//All the predicates mentioned in here are of type org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate
private Predicate<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>>[] getStrategies() {

  List<Predicate<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>> predicates = strategies.stream()
            .map(strategy -> (Predicate<Long, AccountMigrationEvent>>) (key, value) -> strategy.matches(value))
            .collect(toList());

    // branch() method on KStream requires an array so we need to transform our list
    return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Why collect into a list in the first place? Why not use `toArray(Predicate[]::new)` directly on the stream?

Comment: Besides collecting into a `List` being unnecessary, the standard idiom for converting a collection into an array is `predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])`. Some people believed that allocating an array of the same size as the collection was helping performance, but never verified this. The author of [this great article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) actually did and found the opposite. So using a different size than zero just adds potential error sources.

Comment: RealSkeptic: that's a very good point, initially I did it for getting rid of the type check warning but now I realized I just moved it 3 lines below ...

Holger: very interesting article, I never expected that!