# Dynamic number of filters in the same predicate

Tags: java, apache-kafka, java-8, apache-kafka-streams

I'm applying some filters based in user inputs and it works as expected once I can assume I know the number of filters when coding, 2 in below code. Now I'd like to have the number of filters dynamic in my application based in user input so I'm looking for alternatives to increment the lambda function as needed using '&&' and '||' operators. I found similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902587/collection-of-lambda-functions-in-java-streams/55902873) but I could not find a example with dynamic filters in the same predicate like below.

Using Predicate function:

```
final KStream<String, EventMessage>  filter_stream = stream.filter(IsGoodtoGoFilter(Filters));

private Predicate<String, EventMessage> IsGoodtoGoFilter(String[] Filters)  {
    // Logic to parse Dynamic Filters 
    /// .....
    return (k, v) ->  v.getPayload().getDecodedValue(Column1).toString().equals(Value1) && v.getPayload().getDecodedValue(Column2).toString().equals(Value2);
```

Using Predicate test override:

```
        final KStream<String, EventMessage>  filter_stream = stream.filter(new Predicate<String, EventMessage>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(String k, EventMessage v) {
                // Logic to parse Dynamic Filters 
                ///.....
                return v.getPayload().getDecodedValue(Column1).toString().equals(Value1) && v.getPayload().getDecodedValue(Column2).toString().equals(Value2);
              
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you delegate to `java.util.BiPredicate` as it already has the required operators.

For example, if you have a predefined set of predicate options:

```
BiPredicate<String,EventMessage> isAllUppercase = (st, em) -> st.equals(st.toUppercase());
BiPredicate<String,EventMessage> hasSevenLetters = (st, em) -> st.length() == 7;
BiPredicate<String,EventMessage> containsOnlyNumbers = (st, em) -> st.matches("\\d+");
```

Then you can construct a new predicate based on your user's input:

```
BiPredicate<String,EventMessage> filter = isAllUpperCase.and(hasSevenLetters).or(containsOnlyNumbers.negate());
```

Your implementation of Kaka's `Predicate` could then just delegate to `filter.test`. In fact, because they are both functional interfaces, you could likely just use `filter` as a `kstream.Predicate`.

So after `filter` (a `BiPredicate`) is defined, your delegation could be any of the following:

```
Predicate<String, EventMessage> kstreamFilter = (k, v) -> filter.test(k, v);
```

or

```
Predicate<String, EventMessage> kstreamFilter = filter;
```

or you can avoid the kstream `Predicate` altogether:

```
KStream<String, EventMessage> filteredStream = stream.filter(filter);
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern for more details on delegation.

Comment: The problem is I'm using KStream Predicates which does not offer 'and' and 'or' operators. https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Predicate.html

Comment: @mvitor ok I hadn't realised that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: When you say 'delegate to filter.test'. Is to Java.util Predicate ? or it kstream.Predicate all the time ? Not sure if I follow yet. thanks!

Comment: Delegate just means that the implementation details are in another object and your call the appropriate method in that object. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: That would be really impressive however it's throwing below error. Any idea ?

error: incompatible types: BiPredicate<String,EventMessage> cannot be converted to Predicate<? super String,? super EventMessage>
        final KStream<String, EventMessage>  filter_stream = stream.filter(filter);

Comment: I don't have kstream installed so can't really check syntax but you could try declaring the filter as `BiPredicate<? super String,? super EventMessage>` so it matches the kstream interface.